# How to return a block of json in python

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm trying to write a quick api that will search through a json object and return the current account if the iban is the same. If it doesn't find any iban it should return a 404.

This is what I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import abort
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

accounts = {
    "accounts": {
        "account": {
            "naam": "Mark Roording",
            "iban": "NL93RABO4923460458",
            "straat": "Pluviusstraat",
            "straatnummer": 5,
            "postcode": "7321EL",
            "plaats": "Apeldoorn"
        },
        "account": {
            "naam": "Carleen van der Snoek",
            "iban": "NL80INGB7619798757",
            "straat": "Franciscanenstraat",
            "straatnummer": 160,
            "postcode": "1566LC",
            "plaats": "Assendelft"
        },
        "account": {
            "naam": "Maria Lingen",
            "iban": "NL28INGB6291533782",
            "straat": "Weterschoten",
            "straatnummer": 135,
            "postcode": "7381AL",
            "plaats": "Klarenbeek"
        },
        "account": {
            "naam": "Betty Kelder",
            "iban": "NL70INGB6143537119",
            "straat": "Utrechtseweg",
            "straatnummer": 111,
            "postcode": "6862AC",
            "plaats": "Oosterbeek"
        },
        "account": {
            "naam": "Timmie Ruijgrok",
            "iban": "NL41ABNA9079565997",
            "straat": "Kuipersstraat",
            "straatnummer": 27,
            "postcode": "1074EK",
            "plaats": "Amsterdam"
        }
    }

}


@app.route('/get_accountdetails')
def get_accountdetails():
    paramiban = request.args.get('iban', type=str)

    for k, acctinfo in accounts['accounts'].items():
        if acctinfo['iban'] == paramiban:
            response = app.response_class(
                response=json.dumps(acctinfo),
                status=200,
                mimetype='application/json'
            )

            return response
        else:
            return abort(404)
```

So if iban is NL28INGB6291533782 it would return the current account and a 200 so like this:

```
{"naam": "Maria Lingen", "iban": "NL28INGB6291533782", "straat": "Weterschoten", "straatnummer": 135, "postcode": "7381AL", "plaats": "Klarenbeek"}
```

EDIT: so I changed the code and if I type in the last iban it works and returns the value. If it's any other iban it doesn't work.

Comment: You have duplicate keys in your JSON. While not actually forbidden in the standard it does not make any sense. When parsed to Python only one key will remain. I would advise to use a list/an array instead  of the dictionary/object with duplicate keys.

Comment: Okay I made them unique now, but I would not know how to give account2 back for example in the code then.

Comment: it seems you provide real, possibly sensitive data here: real addresses and bank accounts, pls. make that fake

Comment: Oh don't worry, these are all generated. It's dummy data. :D

Comment: That data looks suspiciously legit... mind sharing the BSNs while you're at it?

Comment: Haha, I can assure you it's not. I used https://www.fakenamegenerator.com/ and http://randomiban.com/?country=Netherlands to generate the data.

Comment: don' t use dict as a variable name

Comment: Sure I'll change it.

Comment: While you have made it valid you have also abused an object to do what an array is made for.

Comment: If I am not using it correctly feel free to correct me, however I wouldn't know how to do that I'm still fairly new to python and the way they handle data structures.

Comment: If you have a list of objects, then use an array. That's the one with the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import json

@app.route('/get_accountdetails')
def get_accountdetails():
    iban = request.args.get('iban')

    for dict in accounts:
        if dict['iban'] == iban:
            response = app.response_class(
                 response=json.dumps(dict['account']),
                 status=200,
                 mimetype='application/json'
               )
            return response
        else:
            return abort(404)
```

it will help to send json response with 200 status code.

Comment: Thanks for responding however with that if I use "http://localhost:5000/get_accountdetails?iban=NL28INGB6291533782" I get the following error : 
"TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: check your dictionary, this error was raise from dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You process accounts, while you should process accounts["accounts"]:

```
iban = 'NL41ABNA9079565997'
for k, acctinfo in accounts['accounts'].items():
    if acctinfo['iban'] == iban:
        print(acctinfo)
```

prints:

```
    {
  "naam": "Timmie Ruijgrok",
  "iban": "NL41ABNA9079565997",
  "straat": "Kuipersstraat",
  "straatnummer": 27,
  "postcode": "1074EK",
  "plaats": "Amsterdam"
}
```

Comment: So that works if I spoon feed it the iban, I want to use http://localhost:5000/get_accountdetails?iban=NL41ABNA9079565997 however.

Comment: You should take a look at 'flask_restplus'. I think you will like it if you want to setup a REST interface